# When to use "is a" or "has a"?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, node.js, concepts

In my node.js application, I have a queue class which has `push` and `pop` methods and a `data` property. I have an `Event` class which handles an event and pushes it on to the queue.

If I think object oriented, is the relationship between queue and event better modeled as "is a" (inheritance) or "has a" (composition)?

First approach:

```
var util = require('util'),
    array = [];

function Q(source){
    this.data = source;
}

Q.prototype.push = function(x){
    this.data.push(x);
};

Q.prototype.show = function(){
    console.log(this.data);
};

function Event(y){
    Q.call(this, y);
}

util.inherits(Event,Q);

Event.prototype.trigger = function(bb){
 //some logic
 this.push(bb);
};

var x = new Event(array);
x.trigger('hi');
x.show();
```

Second approach :

```
var array = [];
function Q(source){
    this.data = source;
}

Q.prototype.push = function(x){
    this.data.push(x);
};

Q.prototype.show = function(){
    console.log(this.data);
};

function Event(y){
    this.arr = new Q(y);
}

Event.prototype.trigger = function(bb){
    //some logic
    this.arr.push(bb);
};

var x = new Event(array);
x.trigger('hi');
x.show();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Comment: @gnat thats absoloutly not duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript). you just wast my time by reading that long question and answer. my question is about pros and cons of `is a` and `has a` in the above situation.

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: You need to define what "better" means to you, in this particular case. What are you most concerned with? Least concerned with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, inheritance (is-a) is a *specialization* of composition (has-a). ([from Reg Braithwaite](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/03/is-is-has.html)) Both accomplish the same thing (which is why you can ask a question like this), but inheritance lacks the flexibility of composition. Inheritance makes your code rigid.

From a practical view, this doesn't matter as much in JavaScript since JavaScript isn't limited to single inheritance. What we're calling inheritance is actually some prototype patching and function delegation. There's nothing stopping us from creating a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin#In_JavaScript) from several "types". This has more in common with [Go's type composition](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language) than Java or C#'s inheritance model. It doesn't make your code as rigid.

Still, it does seem strange to say an `Event` is-a `Queue`. Is it really? It seems more likely that an `Event` is a model of some action in your app and it uses (has-a) a `Queue` to manage its workflow. If an `Event` is truly a `Queue`, I should be able to use it anywhere I use a `Queue` without a second thought:

```
var q = new Event();
q.push("hi");
q.pop();
```

This doesn't seem right to me. It's a stretch. This is a perfect place to avoid inheritance in favor of composition.

See also: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: thanks alot scant. i got your point about inheritance and composition.